# Storing Pointers difference in integers?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p1,*p2;
    int m=2,n=3;
    m=p2-p1;
    printf("\np2=%u",p2);
    printf("\np1=%u",p1);   
    printf("\nm=%d",m);       
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output as:

```
p2= 2686792
p1= 1993645620
m= -497739707
```

I have two doubts with the code and output:

1. Since 'm' is an int, it shouldn't take p2-p1 as an input since p1 and p2 both are pointers and m is an integer it should give an error like "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int' " but it isn't. why?
2. Even after it takes the input, the difference isn't valid. Why is it?

Comment: Your p1 and p2 are unitialized.

Comment: 1) The difference between two similarly typed pointers is an integer (or perhaps a long, not sure of the fine print).  2) The difference *is* valid, since the two pointers are uninitialized and hence just "garbage".

Comment: Not to mention, pointer arithmetic depends on the size of the type pointed to.

Comment: Also google 'pointer arithmetic' for more insight.

Comment: my doubt is p2 and p1 are given some garbage values but the difference is not correct.. once given, i guess the garbage values get fixed for the entire code so the difference in above case should be 2686792-1993645620=-1990958828...

Comment: Actually the different is correct (for pointer arithmetic).  (2686792 - 1993645620) / sizeof(int) = -497739707

Answer (score 1):

> *Since 'm' is an int, it shouldn't take p2-p1 as an input since p1 and
>    p2 both are pointers and m is an integer it should give an error like
>   "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int' " but it isn't. why?*

This type of error or warning is depends on the compiler you are using.  C compilers often times give programmers plenty of rope to hang themselves with...

> *Even after it takes the input, the difference isn't valid. Why is it?*

Actually, the difference is correct!  It is using [pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm) to perform the calculation.  So for this example..

**p2= 2686792**

**p1= 1993645620**

Since the pointers are not initialized, they are assigned some garbage values like the ones above. Now, you want to perform the operation p2 - p1, **i.e. you are asking for the memory address that comes exactly p1 memory blocks before p2**. Since p1 and p2 are pointers to integers, the size of a memory block is `sizeof(int)` (almost always 4 bytes).  Therefore:

p2 - p1 = (2686792 - 1993645620) / `sizeof(int)` = (2686792 - 1993645620) / 4 = -497739707

Answer (score 0):

> Since 'm' is an int, it shouldn't take p2-p1 as an input since p1 and p2 both are pointers and m is an integer it should give an error like "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int' " but it isn't. why?

The C++ spec declares this to be legal.
From the C++11 spec 5.7.6:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements.  The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as std::ptrdiff_t in the  header (18.2).

... later in that paragraph...

> Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or
>   one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined.

The result of p2 - p1 is of the same type as std::ptrdiff_t, but nothing says the compiler cannot have defined it as

```
namspace std {
    typedef ptrdiff_t int;
}
```

However, you also do not get a guarentee that this will work on all platforms.  For example, some platforms (especially 64-bit ones) will use a long for ptrdiff_t.  On those platforms your code would fail to compile because it depended on an implementation defined type for ptrdiff_t.

As for your second question, the wording in the C++ spec 5.7.6 suggests why they work the way they work.  The wording indicates that the writers of the language wanted pointer arithmetic to support quick arithmetic while working ones way through an array.   Accordingly, the defined the result of pointer subtraction to yield convenient results when used in the context of manipulating an array.  You could build a language where the difference between two pointers is the difference between their memory addresses in bytes, and you would have a consistent working language.  However, a good language always gets the best bang for their buck.  The authors felt clean manipulation of arrays was more valuable than being able to get the byte-difference.  For example:

```
double* findADouble(double* begin, double* end, double valueToSearchFor)
{
    for (double* iter = begin; iter != end; iter++) {
        if (*iter == valueToSearchFor)
            return iter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would have to have a sizeof in it, and we would have to use += instead of ++.

```
double* findADouble(double* begin, double* end, double valueToSearchFor)
{
    for (double* iter = begin; iter != end; iter += sizeof(double)) {
        if (*iter == valueToSearchFor)
            return iter;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also worth noting in their decision: when the rule was created in C, optimizing compilers were not very good at their job.  iter += sizeof(double) could be compiled down to a much less efficient assembly code than ++iter, even if the two operations are fundamentally doing the same thing.  Modern optimizers have no trouble with this, but the syntax stays.